# Find all the numbers with common index - R

Tags: r

I have two numerics, such that

```
beta: 
  chr4       chr4       chr5       chr7       chr7       chr7 
0.01960784 0.01960784 0.01960784 0.00000000 0.00990099 0.01941748 

coefficients:
  chr1    chr4    chr4    chr7    chr7    chr8 
 0.7605  0.1261  4.3766  5.6856 -0.5194 -0.6355
```

I would like to find all the numbers of the common chromosomes, for example

```
beta:
chr4       chr4          chr7       chr7       chr7 
0.01960784 0.01960784 0.01941748 0.01960784 0.01960784

coefficients:
chr4    chr4    chr7    chr7   
0.1261  4.3766  5.6856 -0.5194
```

What I have done so far:

```
x = beta
f <- mouse$coefficients

common_sites_index <- intersect(names(x), names(f))

reduced_beta <- x[common_sites_index]
reduced_model <- f[common_sites_index]
```

However I'm just getting the first results

```
chr4         chr7       
0.01960784  0.01941748

chr4       chr7    
0.1261    5.6856
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` would return only the first match. Use `%in%` to compare the names and subset the values.

```
reduced_beta <- x[names(x) %in% common_sites_index]
reduced_model <- f[names(f) %in% common_sites_index]
```

You can see the difference in this small example :

```
x <- c(a = 2, b = 3, a = 4)
x['a']
#a 
#2 
x[names(x) %in% 'a']
#a a 
#2 4
```

Comment: it gives me the warning "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" but indeed it works, thank you very much ,)